# Is it necessary to use an ODM framework for Mongodb in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

Now I want to use mongodb as my Python website backend storage, but I am wondering whether it's necessary to use an ODM such as MongoEngine? Or just use mongodb python driver directly?

Any good advice?

Answer (score 0):

Is it strictly necessary? no - you can use the python driver directly without an ODM in the middle.  If you prefer defining schemas and models to crafting/modifying your own schema via normal database operations, then an ODM is probably something you should look into.

A lot of people got used to using this kind of solution when mapping their development data model into a relational database (in that case an ORM).  Because the MongoDB document model more closely maps to an object in your code (for example), you may feel you no longer need this mapping.

It can still be convenient though (as you can see from the popularity of mongoengine, mongoid, morphia and others) - the choice, in the end, is yours.